# Where could the air in the water system be coming from?

Tags: plumbing, water, water-heater, water-pressure

We live on the top two floors of a small brownstone walkup. To get the heating to work upstairs I need to bleed the baseboard heater almost every other day. All faucets in the house sputter, and the water pressure is generally low.

I suspect the water pump is sucking in air somehow. Any ideas? Any way to check this?

Comment: Your baseboard heating system is a closed-loop system that is completely (or should be!) system than your house water. The heating system is driven by a pump, and your home water is driven by municipal city pressure.